# How to navigate from side menu in SwiftUI to new view

Tags: ios, xcode, navigation, swiftui, side-menu

I am working on app which has home view with navigation and side menu. Side menu has 2 levels menu i.e. each menu entries has sub menu(s). Whenever user click on any side sub-menu, app should display new view but i am unable to achieve this behavior. I tried Navigation view in sub-menu but then sub-menu is broken, i also tried to navigateTo but it also did not work.

This is home view which has attached side menu -

```
struct HomePageView: View {
    @State var size = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.6
    
    var body: some View {
       GeometryReader{ geometry in
            NavigationView{
                VStack{
                    ScrollView (.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {
                        anotherView()
                        HStack{
                            Spacer(minLength: 0)
                        }
                    }.frame(width: geometry.size.width)
                }
                .background(Image("background").resizable().scaledToFill().clipped())
                .animation(.spring()).background(Color.lairBackgroundGray)
                .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
                    self.size = 10
                }, label: {
                    Image("menu")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                }).foregroundColor(.appHeadingColor), trailing:
                    Button(action: {
                        withAnimation {
                            print("profile is pressed")
                        }
                    }) {
                        HStack {
                            NavigationLink(destination: ProfileView()) {
                                LinearGradient.lairHorizontalDark
                                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                                    .mask(
                                        Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
                                            .resizable()
                                            .scaledToFit()
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ).navigationBarTitle("Home", displayMode: .inline)
                 .animation(.spring())
                }.padding(.top, UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.top)
            HStack{
                menu(size: self.$size)  // --> Side menu
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                    .padding(.leading, -self.size)
                    .offset(x: -self.size)
                Spacer().background(Color.lairBackgroundGray)
            }.padding(.top, UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.top)
            .animation(.spring())
           }
    }
}
```

Below is side menu view, it is created based on State variable  -

```
struct menu : View {
    @Binding var size : CGFloat
    @State var logout: Bool = false
    @State private var didSubMenuPressed: Bool = false
    
    @State var sideMenuEntries = [
        SideMenuData(index: 0, imageName: "info.circle",
                     menuText: "Info",
                     subMenu: ["Info1", "Info2", "Info3", "Info4"],
                     expand: false),
        SideMenuData(index: 1, imageName: "doc.on.doc",
                     menuText: "Documents",
                     subMenu: ["Documents1", "Documents2"],
                     expand: false)
    ]
    
    var body : some View{
        VStack (alignment: .leading){
            HStack{
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    self.size =  UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.6
                }) {
                    Image("close").resizable()
                        .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                        .padding()
                }
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .clipShape(Circle())
            }
            ForEach (sideMenuEntries.indices) { index in
                VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 0, content: {
                    HStack{
                        Image(self.sideMenuEntries[index].imageName).resizable().frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                        Text(self.sideMenuEntries[index].menuText).fontWeight(.heavy).foregroundColor(.white)
                        if self.sideMenuEntries[index].subMenu.count > 1 {
                            Image(systemName: self.sideMenuEntries[index].expand ? "chevron.compact.up" : "chevron.compact.down")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                        
                        Image("logout-1").resizable().frame(width: 25, height: 25)//.padding(.leading, 5)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                        Text(self.sideMenuEntries[index].menuText).fontWeight(.heavy).foregroundColor(.white)
                        if self.logout {
                            //
                        }
                        
                    }
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.sideMenuEntries[index].expand.toggle()
                    }
                    if self.sideMenuEntries[index].expand {
                        VStack (alignment: .leading){
                            ForEach (self.sideMenuEntries[index].subMenu.indices) { index1 in
                                Button(action: {
                                    print("\(self.sideMenuEntries[index].subMenu[index1]) is pressed")
                                    self.size =  UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.6
                                    self.didSubMenuPressed.toggle()
                                }){
                                    Text(self.sideMenuEntries[index].subMenu[index1])
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                }
                                .padding([.top, .bottom], 7)
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.top, 14)
                        .padding(.leading, 34)
                    }
                })
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(.leading, 40)
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.3)
        .background(LinearGradient(
            gradient: Gradient(
                colors: [.buttonGradientStartColor, .buttonGradientEndColor]),
            startPoint: .top,
            endPoint: .bottom))
        // if u want to change swipe menu background color
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it would be better to use NavigateView so that is it is navigated to any other view and having navigation like will help user to come back to Home view.

Comment: Anyone can help me please?

Comment: @pawello2222    any suggestion to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to achieve this behavior , create State var in HomePageview and Binding var in menu and that resolved my problem.